# executing RSYNC command in jenkins

Tags: linux, jenkins, deployment, continuous-integration

I'm trying to deploy my code to a remote server.  So far I've tried

- Publish over SSH Plugin: the problem is that I'm unable to keep file permissions
- Rsync command: this keeps the file permissions, but the problem is that I don't know how to set the password for it to work automatically

This is what I get:

```
[JenkinsBuild] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/lib/jenkins/tmp/hudson4646064064846581974.sh
+ rsync -PSauve ssh --exclude=JenkinsBuild app bower.json config gruntfile.js karma.conf.js LICENSE.md Makefile node_modules package.json Procfile protractor.conf.js public README README.md server.js john@192.168.2.10:/srv/dp/prod
Host key verification failed.
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(600) [sender=3.0.6]
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I replaced the know_host files but I was still having issues.  so for anyone that has issues with the know_host file you would fix the offending key by doing a:

```
ssh-keygen -R hostnameOfOfendingKey
```

and this will remove the ofending key and now your known_host file is working again.

NOW  to resolve the other issue I found the answer in this other place: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755418/executing-rsync-in-jenkins/25770519#25770519

and This was what I did to solve it

```
sudo su jenkins -s /bin/bash
```

then once as jenkins user copy my ssh key to the server I want to connect/execute commands in, etc

```
ssh-copy-id myuser@TheRemoteserver.com
```

it then will present you this

```
myuser@TheRemoteserver.com's password: 
Now try logging into the machine, with "ssh 'myuser@TheRemoteserver.com'", and check in:

  .ssh/authorized_keys

to make sure we haven't added extra keys that you weren't expecting.
```

then I did this for testing purposes:

```
bash-4.1$ rsync -PSauve ssh --exclude=JenkinsBuild /srv/pd/* myuser@TheRemoteserver.com:/srv/pdc/test1
```

and it passed without asking for password or anything. Notice that I'm still log as jenkins.

So now when I created the Jenkins job with some shell commands as part of the build it will work as expected :D

Answer (score 4):

```
Host key verification failed.
```

The account running jenkins likely has a bad value for the host key for the machine you are sshing to in `~/.ssh/known_hosts.`

Comment: thanks this gave me a hint on what was wrong, and since I don't have enough points I can't give you a +1

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.

In my case jenkins was not executing rsync with the expected user (jenkins) but with another (jboss in my case)
adding '`whoami`' to the script and using ssh verbose:

```
rsync -e "ssh -v" .......
```

helped to find the problem.